# Manage state in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page with around 20+ controls. Within this page I have a partial View which I am using to create an editable grid. This grid has Add New Row/Remove Row buttons on click of which data entered in the textboxes in grid row gets added to the grid.

Whenever I click these 2 buttons, my page is getting refreshed due to which whatever data is being entered by the user in the 20+ controls of main page is lost.

I have tried hopelessly searching for solutions quite some time, but still trying my luck out here. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is the buttons that are clicked of type: Submit? looks like a postback is happening... MVC unlike WebForms does not have viewstate to keep the values, so you can't refresh the page or get the data that you need back again on refreshing the page...

Comment: Could you provide more information about your technology underground? I did not understand what do you mean "control" in MVC 4. Are you using AJAX?

Comment: Appreciate ur quick response Aram & Miro... 

I am using Razor design using MVC4 framework..Wrt controls, I meant dropdowns, listboxes, textboxes , checkboxes 

The partial page is holding the dynamic editable grid

Comment: Agreed with Miro. Take a look at using AJAX and don't refresh the entire page, just portions of it when forms get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend you to use full jquery mechanisms to add or remove rows. You can easily add or remove HTML elements. All you have to care about is to maintain the numbering system. I suggest you to use a view model that contains a list of objects that you need to add or remove. At first render it normally by providing list of objects (from database or other source, if required). After this define your add and remove buttons to type button and play with jquery to add remove table rows or even divs. After adding or removing required element, reorganize your numbering. At submit you can use either full postback or ajax postback. If Any confusion, let me know.